# restarting minion using python

Tags: python, salt-stack

Is there any way to restart minions with python code? using local.cmd('*', 'cmd.run', ['net stop salt-minion']). Will shutting down the minions and making them non-responsive is right?

Comment: OK I got it myself, 
local.cmd('*', 'cmd.run', ['net stop salt-minion && net start salt-minion'])
will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I know `service.restart` and even `pkg.install` works with salt-minion:

```
local.cmd('*', 'service.restart', ['salt-minion'])
```

Of course, you ought to test this on a subset of minions first.